# NSMuttableArray,TableView , Switch Views Programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios

I am a new Programmer of Iphone..... i have a little problem in accessing the NSMuttable array in my programe...

i am generating a view programmatically on button click .... code on button click is

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked
    {
    secondView=[[TabBarSearchSecondView alloc]init];
    [myView addSubview:secondView.view];
}
```

inTabBarSearchSecondView .h file.....

```
@interface ......

NSMuttableArray *searchResult;

@end

@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMuttableArray *searchResult;
```

**in TabBarSearchSecondView .m file.........**

```
@synthesize searchResult;


- (void)loadView
{


    CGRect cgRct = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480, 320); //define size and position of view 

    myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cgRct]; //initilize the view    


    //open database

    DbOpenAndClose *dbObject=[[DbOpenAndClose alloc]init];
    [dbObject openDatabase];


    //for call of search showroom

    SearchProduct *object=[[SearchProduct alloc]init];

    searchResult=[object searchShowrooms:productname:cityname];

    [dbObject closeDatabase];


        count=[searchResult count];/// print 3 because 3 record match in database


    UITableView *table=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4,80,312,325)        style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    //table.delegate=self;

    table.dataSource=self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    //NSLog(@"%i", [searchResult count]);

    return [searchResult count]; ///Not accessible here...Application Crash Here...
}
```

thanks for giving your valueable time for my Code...... thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to **retain** the `searchResult` array....

after this code

```
    searchResult=[object searchShowrooms:productname:cityname];
```

retain the `searchResult`. otherwise it is **released**.. **retain** the `searchResult` like this.

```
[searchResult retain];
```

Comment: thanks...alot..... i only use [searchResult retain]; and my programs work fines......

Comment: why my searchResult release...(if i not retain it)..... can you explain me in short...or give me any tutorial :)

Comment: you have to allocate an array otherwise it is released at any time.

Comment: check out this link http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH